# How can I give back to the rpg.stackexchange community besides answering questions?

Tags: discussion, community

I am a fledgling game master running a Pathfinder group. With only D&D 4e experience as a player, I sometimes struggle to grasp all the details of Pathfinder rules. RPG.stackexchange was and is tremendously helpful to me.

So, I would really like to give back to the community. I find it a bit hard to answer questions, because I am myself still struggling with understanding the finer details of the Pathfinder rules. Also, I find that when I try to answer a question, often someone else has given a good answer that does not really leave room to add (which is a good thing!), and I don't want to add redundancy.

What other ways are there to help improve rpg.stackexchange for everybody involved?

Answer (score 20):

## Ask Questions

If there are things you don't understand, create a question, there are almost certainly others with similar queries.

You add to the pool of knowledge, and are even rewarded yourself with some nice Rep!

Answer (score 15):

### Spread the good answers to other places on the web

You can provide links to useful questions and answers to other places on the internet.  That spreads the usefulness of the stack's output, and it helps the stack attract more visitors.  You'll also get a few badges as time goes on and more people click the links you offer.  For example, the [Publicist](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/56/publicist), [Booster](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/55/booster) and [Announcer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/announcer) badges may crop up in your award pile, depending on how many people follow the link.

Use the share feature for the linked question or answer, and it will give you credit.  :)    For example, if I click on 'share' for Kuerten's nice answer, this becomes the address: `https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8844/22566`

Everything up to 8844 is the answer link; the 22566 tells the system that I provided the link to share with others (it's my user ID).

Answer (score 9):

## You can edit posts and ask questions

If you are uncomfortable answering questions of the systems you know, then you can edit older questions/answers. Remember to follow the [editing guidelines](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/editing). Older questions usually feature problems with tags, if you are looking for a start.

Important note: since you haven't hit the 2k reputation mark, your editions will go the review queue and require approval.

Also, remember: making questions also "gives back" to this community. To create and promote research and information is what the Stack Exchange sites are for.

Answer (score 6):

Disable adblock on SE

They don't sell ad space to malicious content providers and it helps them pay the bills.